# Framework/api in Java for Client-Server-Client architecture

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, zeromq

I am currently working on a project where there are client systems, user systems and a server. For our example lets use **Client A**, **Server**, **User A.**

**Client A** sends a keep alive packet to the server and the server stores the socket info as a hashmap/ list with the client ids. This way more number of clients can add into the hashmap/ list.

**User A** wants to send an information to **client A**, so it connects to the server to send a message to **client A**. The server fetches the relevant socket information from the hashmap/list and passes it over to **User A** or the server ties up both the sockets together.

A bit clueless in this part of merging sockets together. Any views or suggestions is appreciated. Currently I am trying out ZeroMQ but not getting anywhere with it, any other frameworks, apis or libraries I can look into?

Comment: So you want a server that authorizes and creates a p2p connection between two clients? What's the definition for your "User" and "Client" and how are they different from each other?

Comment: @Nick Savage In my scenario, the Client device is a printer and the User device can either be a PC/Mobile/tablet etc. and the message would be like "Printer2232322|0" or "Printer2232322|<<request download>>" etc., **server that authorizes and creates a p2p connection between two clients** - The answer is pretty much yes, but am still bit unclear on how the connection can be established between the two clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass connection to Client A over to User A, but you can tie up both the sockets together. This requires 2 threads: one reads from user socket and writes to client socket, and another reads from client socket and writes to user socket. If 2 threads is too many a resource consumption, consider using NIO libraries (there are many).